# Trying to make a Visual Studio 2015 Add-In: SDK, API.... (Reagrding ribbon or whatever its called)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, add-in, visual-studio-sdk

I have been trying to get my head around the SDK API for visual studio for a while now. The problem is I know what I want/need to do. However I can not find a code example or API documentation anywhere that allows me to do what I want :(

I know its possible just I cant find documentation to show how.

I want to add another sidebar ribbon for all open files similar to how the breakpoint works (And many test add-ins for VS, NCrunch comes to mind...) that is blank as standard but when clicked allows some logic to be run to add a comment on that line.

Once added a Icon will be then displayed on that line allowing you to click the icon to view/edit the left comment. (The storage of this etc. is not a problem with the implementation I am doing) I just really need to know how to tell the API to add a new ribbon/side thing and plumb in the required logic :/

[image: Example breakpoint side image]

If this isn't possible I also had the idea of highlighting the word and again a icon popping up but that seems even more annoying to implement hence why I chose the side option if it is at all possible :/

Thanks in Advance to anyone who helps :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "sidebar ribbon" is called an editor margin. See [Editor Extension Points](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885244.aspx).

> Implement an IWpfTextViewMargin interface to define a margin. You must
>   also implement the IWpfTextViewMarginProvider interface to create the
>   margin.

Comment: YES thank you for that!

Finding out its correct name is a great starting point :D
Shall see what I can do with it!

Is there any good code examples of this anywhere you know of?

Thanks In Advance! (Gonna go read the documentation now!)

Comment: There is an Editor Margin new item that you can add to your vsix project. (Though it creates a bottom margin.)